# Persistent names for usb-serial devices using udev rule, not working

Tags: usb, sound, alsa, udev

I have a computer with Ubuntu that has connected several usb soundcards. I can play sound in one of them by writting a command like:

**`aplay -D plughw:1,0 sound.mp3`**

**`aplay -D plughw:2,0 sound.mp3`**

The problem is that the "1,0" value changes depending of the order in which the usb soundcards are plugged. I need to permanently assign a certain usb soundcard to plug 3,0, for example. Even if only there is one soundcard connected.

I've following this guide:
***http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/***

In here: ***`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-vmware-scsi-udev.rules`*** I have

**`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0d8c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0102", SYMLINK+="ardu"`**

And it seems to work because if I type:

**`ls -l /dev/ardu`**

I get:

**`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 sep  5 01:32 /dev/ardu -> input/event5`**

And this message is only returned in case the specific soundcard is plugged.

Now, If I type:

**`aplay -D /dev/ardu sound.mp3`**

The soundcard is not found. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: USB audio devices are not USB serial devices. If you have two different devices, see http://alsa.opensrc.org/MultipleUSBAudioDevices. If you have two identical devices, see "Identify two identical audio devices" on http://alsa.opensrc.org/Udev.

Comment: Damn fuck shit man, the part of "Writing udev rules", in http://alsa.opensrc.org/Udev,  is exactly what I needed. Fuck fuck shit. Thanks. I don't even need the vendor/producer/serial ID's, they get an alias when connected to the correspondent USB port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved in the comments by CL.

Basically, follow this url tutorial to the letter, just the correspondent chapter (Writing udev rules - **Identify two identical audio devices**): http://alsa.opensrc.org/Udev

In the end, I have each USB assigned permanently to a USB soundcard, and the USB dont change with reset.

And I can do:

**`$ aplay -D hw:Room1 something.wav`**

**`$ aplay -D hw:Room2 something.wav`**

Room1 is a USB soundcard connected permanently to usb1, and Room2 is the same with another usb.

Using `-D default:Room1` gave me problems with surround, but `-D hw:Room1` didn't, probably that's due to my personal `.asoundrc` file.

Making it work with a hub was a pain in the ass. I ended changing 2 things from the guide: I did set the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/85-my-usb-audio.rules` with a higher number that the current .rules file (the current .rules file was like `99-something.rules`, so I did `100-my-usb-audio.rules`).

And after each change in .rules file, I ended reseting with:

**`sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`**

The rest is exactly like the guide.

Comment: I've added some stuff, but basically, people from the future, follow the linked guide with the chapter "Identify two identical audio devices"

Comment: Could check your own answer as the accepted one, so other users can find it easily.